# Sorting a vector of vectors while maintaining relative order

Tags: c++, sorting, vector

I've been trying to implement a c++ program that sorts a vector of vectors in ascending order while maintaining the current order in case of ties (e.g. if vector a is before vector b, then a stays before b). This is the code that I have now. Any tips would be appreciated!

EDIT: By the way, c is the column that you sort by

```cpp
sort(v.begin(), v.end(), [=] (vector<int> &a, vector<int> &b) {
      if (a[c] == b[c]) {
            int d1 = find(v.begin(), v.end(), a)-v.begin();
            int d2 = find(v.begin(), v.end(), b)-v.begin();
            return d1 < d2;
      }
      return a[c] < b[c];
});
```

Comment: What is `c` in here?

Comment: the column that you need to sort the vector of vectors by

Answer (score 1):

Just use [`std::stable_sort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/stable_sort) and provide criteria to sort by:

```
std::stable_sort(v.begin(), v.end(), [=] (vector<int> &a, vector<int> &b) {
      return a[c] < b[c];
});
```

> Sorts the elements in the range [first, last) in non-descending order. **The order of equivalent elements is guaranteed to be preserved**.

emphasis is mine

Comment: Oh wow, I didn't realize there was a built in function for that, thanks a lot

Comment: @SamLiu deleting your question after you get your answer is not the best way to say thank you.

Comment: Wait a second, my program failed to compile, something about an error in the "[=]" part. Any ideas why?

Comment: Sorry, I'm brand new to this website. I figured it was a dumb question.

Comment: The lambda should take its parameters by `const ref`: `[=] (const std::vector<int> &a, const std::vector<int> &b) { return a[c] < b[c]; });`